# specify content type of an attachment in sql server sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, email, sp-send-dbmail

How can I specify the **content type** of an attachment when sending emails using **sp_send_dbmail**? The content type is specified as *application/octet-stream* for Zip, PDF files. But I need to change it to *application/zip*, *application/pdf*.

The "file_attachments" parameter takes absolute paths of the attachments. Can not find a place to specify content type.

I am using SQL Server 2005/2008

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I created a UserVoice issue for this (since the same is true in SQL 2017): https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35457874-allow-specifying-content-type-for-database-mail-at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done. If you need to specify content types, you'll have to use another method for sending mail.

A SQL Agent job triggering a script/executable in the language of your choice is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: yep. easy methods have their limits